# how can i get an accurate count based on max date when joining 3 tables when one of the join fields is many to 1 in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So, I have 3 tables that I am attempting to get counts for based on a groupid, and a task code.  There are a few issues I am having as some of the relationships are many to one, which I think is somehow inflating my counts.  I will list my 3 tables with the pertinent attributes.

task_table contains:

task_code - would like to get the counts of each one in a group id, would like to use the latest instance basedon event date.

sol_id -used to join to worktable; many sol_id to one m_id is possible

edate -need to use to get one record

cur_id - where cur_id = 1 in the where clause

worktable contains:

sol_id - used to join to task_table

m_id - used to join to grouptable

grouptable contains:

m_id

groupid- used to group the task_code to get count

I'd like the end result to look like:

```
group_id    task_count  task
5555        45          A
5555        4           N
5624        67          A
5624        23          O
5624        42          X
```

I have been attempting to run a number of queries, but the counts I am getting back do not look correct.  I am concerned that it is somehow returning more than one instance of the m_id somehow?  Here is the query in question:

```
select  c.groupid, count(c.groupid) group_count, a.task_code from task_table a
join worktable b
on a.sol_id = b.sol_id
join grouptable c
on b.m_id= c.m_id
where   a.cur_id = 1 and a.task_code is not null 
group by c.groupid, a.task_code;
```

If I add 'edate = (select max(edate) from task_table)' in the where clause, it returns an empty table.

I am unsure how to incorporate edate to get only the newest record that fits the criteria in the where clause.  The reason I think I want to use this is because there could be more than one sol_id that is associated with a m_id, so i'd just like to include only the newest record with a cur_id in the count. Thank you for your time.

sample data

task_table

```
task_code  sol_id  edate   cur_id
A          23      6/7/09    1
A          24      6/4/09    1
A          23      6/10/09   0
B          45      6/2/09    1
B          42      6/3/09    1
C          34      10/8/10   0
C          83      9/10/09   1
```

work table

```
sol_id    m_id
23        1234
24        1234
45        1832
42        1343
83        7623
```

group table

```
m_id  group_id
1234   A76
1832   Y23
1343   A76
7623   Y23
```

looking at these tables, the result should look like the following

```
group_id    task_count  task
A76       2         A            
Y23       1         C
```

( A76  should only count sol_id 23 and 42)
( Y23  should only count sol_id 83)

Comment: Give us the actual CREATE TABLE layout of the important columns and a sample of data so we can run your query and see the issue/work on it easier. I'm having a difficult time separating what columns are in which table, and whether you want unique task codes counted or just the number of times a task code appears. You can throw all this into a fiddle and share the link, or just paste them into your post, but anything that isn't an image will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Coffee, I've added some sample data.  What I need is to count ONLY the most recent task_code in the group.  So if there are multiple tasks all that end up with the same m_id, i just need the most recent one and it's value.and only if the cur_id = 1.  Think of the m_id as a house and the groupid like a city.  I just want to count the house one time with the most recent task_code in the group (city) its in.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a conflict in your requested data result. According to your own sample, A76 should have a task_count of 2: sol_id 23, which has Task A, and sol_id 42, which has Task B. It's not possible to have it return a row like you have at your example result table because it would need to group by TASK_CODE, which means losing the COUNT(task_code). Can't have it both ways.

In order to obtain only the most recent edate, I did a separate calculation to location that max(edate) by task_code, then joined it back to obtain the sol_id. If this isn't accurate for your data set, you'll need to determine another way of obtaining max(edate). This works for your sample set.

```sql
with recentTasks as (
   select task_code, max(edate) as recentDate
   from task_table m 
   where cur_id = 1
     and task_code is not null 
   group by task_code
), recentTaskWithSols as (
  select m.task_code, m.recentDate as edate, t.sol_id
  from recentTasks m 
  join task_table t on m.task_code = t.task_code AND m.recentDate = t.edate
  where t.cur_id = 1
)
select c.group_id, 
  count(a.sol_id) task_count
from group_table c
join work_table b on c.m_id = b.m_id 
join recentTaskWithSols a on b.sol_id = a.sol_id 
group by c.group_id;
```

gives the result:

```
+------------------------+
| GROUP_ID  | TASK_COUNT |
+------------------------+
|    A76    |     2      |
|    Y23    |     1      |
+-----------+------------+
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55efd9c94d5ee67362fc763b874a69be).